# Replace NA with previous occurrence

Tags: r, na

This is a sample of my data from CSV. It contains ~10 columns.

```
    Product_id    Product_Weight    Product_Name    Shop_Name ...
[1]    A             10                xxxx            Walmart
[2]    B             12                yyyy            Target
[3]    C             11                zzzz            Target
[4]    A             NA                xxxx            Walmart
[5]    C             NA                zzzz            Target
```

I would like to fill NA's in row 4 and 5 with 10 and 11 respectively (since the product weight of A and C are already known from row 1 and 3). I want the final data frame to be like this

```
    Product_id    Product_Weight    Product_Name    Shop_Name ...
[1]    A             10                xxxx            Walmart
[2]    B             12                yyyy            Target
[3]    C             11                zzzz            Target
[4]    A             10                xxxx            Walmart
[5]    C             11                zzzz            Target
```

What is the best way to do this in R?

Comment: Are these weights always set so that a Product_id - Product_name combination will return the same weight?

Comment: @lmo Yes they are.

Comment: Another Q&A about replacing NA's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694313/handle-continous-missing-values-in-time-series-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);
df %>% group_by(Product_id) %>% fill(Product_Weight)

Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
Groups: Product_id [3]

  Product_id Product_Weight Product_Name Shop_Name
      (fctr)          (int)       (fctr)    (fctr)
1          A             10         xxxx   Walmart
2          A             10         xxxx   Walmart
3          B             12         yyyy    Target
4          C             11         zzzz    Target
5          C             11         zzzz    Target
```

The result is sorted by Product_id though.

Comment: cant dplyr do this without reordering?

Answer (score 9):

Although the question asked for the "previous occurrence" this would have the disadvantage that if the first `Product_Weight` in any `Product_id` were `NA` then it could not be filled in even if we knew the `Product_Weight` from a subsequent `Product_id` so instead of using the previous occurrence we take the mean of all non-NAs with the same `Product_id`.  Since these should all be the same their mean is their common value.

If you really do want the previous occurrence use the `Prev` function where:

```
Prev <- function(x) na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE)
```

in place of `na.aggregate` in (1) and (3) and do not use (2).

The following solutions have the advantages that they all:

- preserve the order of the input
- work even if the first `Product_Weight` in any `Product_id` is NA
- do not modify the input

The first solution has the additional advantage of being only one line of code (plus a `library` statement) and the second solution has the additional advantage of not using any packages.

**1) zoo::na.aggregate** We use `na.aggregate` in the zoo package (which replaces all NAs with the average of the non-NAs) and we apply it to `Product_Weight` separately for each `Product_id`.

```
library(zoo)
transform(DF, Product_Weight = ave(Product_Weight, Product_id, FUN = na.aggregate))
```

giving:

```
  Product_id Product_Weight Product_Name Shop_Name
1          A             10         xxxx   Walmart
2          B             12         yyyy    Target
3          C             11         zzzz    Target
4          A             10         xxxx   Walmart
5          C             11         zzzz    Target
```

**2) No packages** Alternately use `Mean` in place of `na.aggregate` where `Mean` is defined as:

```
Mean <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**3) dplyr/zoo**  Add row numbers, group by the `Product_id`, fill in the NAs as in the prior solutions using either `na.aggregate` as shown below or `Mean`, arrange back to the original order and remove the row numbers:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DF %>% 
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
   group_by(Product_id) %>% 
   mutate(Product_Weight = na.aggregate(Product_Weight)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   arrange(row) %>% 
   select(-row)
```

**Note:** This was used for the input `DF` :

```
Lines <- "    Product_id    Product_Weight    Product_Name    Shop_Name
    A             10                xxxx            Walmart
    B             12                yyyy            Target
    C             11                zzzz            Target
    A             NA                xxxx            Walmart
    C             NA                zzzz            Target"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution with base R commands:

```
#   create lookup table with item and weight combinations
lookup<-unique(df[complete.cases(df[ ,1:2]),])

#     find the NAs needing replacement: which(is.na(df$weight))
#     find index in lookup tabe:match(df$a[which(is.na(df$weight))
#     subset: df$weight[which(is.na(df$weight))
df$weight[which(is.na(df$weight))]<-lookup$weight[match(df$Product_id[which(is.na(df$weight))], lookup$Product_id)]
```

Most likely not as efficient as the dplyr/tidyr solution mentioned above.